# Displaying the time in a textfield from date picker

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am trying to display the time in the datePicker in a textfield. I have gotten this far

```
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(112, 88, 97, 30)];
textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
[self.view addSubview:textField];

UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
datePicker.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
datePicker.minuteInterval = 5;
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeTime;

[textField setInputView:datePicker];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle: NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
textField.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
```

But the textfield wont change

Comment: What have you done to debug it?

Comment: Debug? nothing i guess

Comment: Why not?  Don't you know how to do basic debugging?  Do you expect your code to work first time, every time?

Answer (score 3):

What does your `-(void)datePickerValueChanged:` method look like?

Does it look like the following:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateStyle: NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
textField.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
```

where `textField` is a the textField that is being edited and `datePicker` is the date picker whose value was changed?

Comment: I had to change the textfield to _textfield and the datepicker to _datepicker. But it still doesnt even show the date in the textfield

Comment: Do I need a method to update the textfield?

Comment: Update your question to show exactly what is in your datePickerValueChanged: method.